# Timings for Tahajjud Prayer

Tags: salat, time, tahajjud

Salaam,
Actually I am a little confused I hope someone can assist me. I want to pray Tahajjud but I am confused about the timings. I usually pray Isha after I come home at around 12 Am and I usually go sleep at 2 or 2:30 am. Now I also have to wake up at 5 am for Fajr. So i want to ask can I pray Tahajjud at 2 am when I am about to sleep? Because if i go to sleep at 2 am then it won't be possible for me to wake up again at 3 am to pray Tahajjud. So can I pray Tahajjud at 2 am? Fajr time in my city starts at around 4:20 am.

Comment: `I usually pray Isha after I come home at around 12 Am` This is time too late for Isha. It is recommended to pray it earlier. Praying Salah in its time is one of the conditions to be accepted. If you are having difficulties with it then consider combining Maghrib and Isha.

Comment: I am at work that time :(. My shift ends at 11:00 pm. My Boss allows me to pray Asar and Magrib in the Mosque but when I asked him for Isha he didn't allowed me and told me to pray when I reach home. I know I should pray in the mosque but what can I do in this situation? Isha time in my country is 9pm. I don't think the Isha time ends at 12 am.

Answer (score 1):

Timing for Tahajjud start right after Isha until Fajr. You may pray at anytime during that duration. But the best time is last third of the night which may be between 2:00 AM to 4:20 AM in you case. Allah knows best.

Comment: I have heard that Tahajjud prayer isn't valid if you pray it without sleeping. I have heard you should take a nap even if it's 10 minutes for Tahajjud Prayer. Can I pray Tahajjud while being awake and then go to sleep.

Comment: That is incorrect. You can pray tajajjud right after Isha and then go to sleep. No problem.